# Where does the tradition of shell prompts in code snippets come from?

Tags: history, command-line, shell

Most code samples I see that demonstrate shell code preface each command with `$`. Having a prefix makes sense, but I'm confused as to why `$` is used in particular. Some other symbol, like `!`, that can be copied and pasted into a prompt without affecting the command's execution makes far more sense to me. So where does this notation come from?

Comment: You can have a look here on SuperUser:
[What is the origin of the UNIX $ (dollar) prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/57575/what-is-the-origin-of-the-unix-dollar-prompt)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$` is the default prompt prefix for a non-escalated bourn or sh shell on most *nix systems.  It signifies that the code exemplified should be executed using one of those associated shells.  zsh and csh have `%` as a prefix.  The fish shell uses `>`.  Putting the prefix is simply a quick way to let the reader know what shell the command is destined for.

Comment: More often than for fish, `>` would be used for cmd.exe – of course this depends on the context.

Comment: @amon cmd.exe can barely be considered as a shell

Comment: @grasGendarme ;-) – but this doesn't matter: cmd.exe is the default text shell on Windows (technically, explorer.exe is the default shell), and it does see a significant amount of use. Simple commands look the same in cmd.exe as they do in bash, but differences WRT quoting (`'` vs `"`) and escaping (backslashes, glob expressions), as well as advanced operators often make it a necessity to indicate which shell you are using.

Comment: In instructions that occasionally require root, it's common to see `$` and `#` used to indicate which operations require escalation.